# How to set autoplay for my iframeHtml in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I use ngx-embed-video/dist for my video section on web page. I try to set autoplay like it is write in documentation but it don't work for me. Who can help me with fixing it ?

Documentation : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-embed-video

Here I set iframeHtml

```
    loadVideo() {
        if (this.validUrl.transform(this.video.url)) {
            this.iframeHtml = this.embedService.embed(this.video.url, {
                query: { autoplay: 1 }
            });
        }
    }
```

There I set the iframe in html

```
 <div *ngIf="load && (video.url | validUrl)" class="videoPlayer" [innerHTML]="iframeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: Can you check the console ? Maybe the autoplay has been prevented by the browser...

Comment: Console is clear, no errors :(